# Why is the barrier cone of a convex set a cone?

Tags: convex-analysis, convex-cone

Barier cone $L$ of a convex set C is defined as $\{x^*| \langle x, x^* \rangle \le \beta, x\in C\}$ for some $\beta \in \mathbb{R}$. However, consider a scenario when $x_1\in L$, $\beta>0$ and $\langle x, x_1 \rangle > 0$ for all $x\in C$. The we can make $\alpha x_1$ arbitrary big, so $\alpha \langle x, x_1 \rangle$ is bigger that $\beta$. Thus, $x_1 \notin L$. Where is the problem with such reasoning?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've misunderstood the definition of a barrier cone.  In particular, we have
$$
\newcommand{ip}[1]{\left\langle #1 \right \rangle}
L = \{x^* \mid 
\exists \beta_{x^*} \text{ such that }
\ip{x,x^*} \leq \beta_{x^*} \text{ for all }x \in C\}
$$

Or, in other words,
$$
L = \{x^* \mid \sup_{x \in C} \ip{x,x^*} \text{ is finite}\}
$$
If we take $\alpha \,x^*$ instead of $x^*$, then our old supremum is multiplied by $|\alpha|$ to get the new supremum, but this new supremum is still finite.  Or, in the notation of my first definition, we can define
$$
\beta_{\alpha\,x^*} = |\alpha|\, \beta_{x^*}
$$
to find that $\alpha\, x^*$ is a member of $L$.

So, $L$ is *indeed* a cone.

Comment: Thank you for the explanation. I thought that $\beta$ should be the same for all $x^*$. Is it correct that a barrier cone for a bounded convex set is whole $\mathbb{R}^n$?

Comment: @ashim yes, that's right.